# 配列の中の数がいくつ重複しているか表示

Tags: php

```
$data = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
  $tmp[] = array_rand($data);
}
foreach ($tmp as $item) {
  echo $item . "\n";
}
```

この中から6個の数をランダムに表示させ、どの数が何個重複したのかを表示させたいのですが、どうやればいいですか？

Comment: [PHP: array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP に標準で付いている [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-count-values.php) 関数を用いると、分布を数えることができます。

```
/* 元々のデータ配列 */
$data = range(0, 9);
/* 重複を許してランダムに $data から取ってきたデータが入る配列 */
$items = [];

/* 6個ランダムに取ってくる */
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $items[] = array_rand($data);
}

/* 統計を取る */
$stat = array_count_values($items);

/* 出力する */
echo "items: ";
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item, " ";
}
echo "\n";

echo "statistics: \n";
foreach ($stat as $item => $count) {
    echo "  ", $item, ": ", $count, " times\n";
}
```

<sub>-- この回答は、[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39550/%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B0%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A4%E9%87%8D%E8%A4%87%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA#comment40026_39550)を元に書かれたものです。</sub>